# Custom-Component | Cannot access 'store' before initialization

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to access the vuex store inside my custom-component. I create the component like:

```
import {
    defineCustomElement
} from 'vue';
import expensemain from '~/components/expense_editor/Main.ce.vue';

const CustomElement = defineCustomElement(expensemain);
window.customElements.define('expense-custom', CustomElement);
```

And import the store like:

```
import store from "../../store/store.js";

export default {
    props: {
        data: JSON,
        expense_voucher_data: JSON
    },
    setup(props) {
        let store = store.state.expense;
        console.log(store);
```

But can't access it cause it seems not to be initialized.

Inside the store.js it is, tho:

```
const store = createStore({
    modules: {
        signup,
        expense
    }
});

export default store;
```

I can't use `app.use` inside main.js cause it's a custom component. How would I import the store to be able to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nearly got it right. The solution was as simple as it could've been:

```
import store from "../../store/store.js";    // import created store

export default {
    props: {
        data: JSON,
        expense_voucher_data: JSON
    },
    setup(props) {
       store.state.moduleName  // direct access to module state
       store.getters           // getters
       store.dispatch          // actions
       store.commit            // mutations
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```js
import store from "../../store/store.js";
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
    props: {
        data: JSON,
        expense_voucher_data: JSON
    },
    setup(props) {
        // let store = store.state.expense;
        const store = useStore();
        console.log(store);
```

And if it dosen't work, you'd better check [Vuex guide of Composition API](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html).

Comment: The problem wasn't composition api. Rather the usage of `defineCustomComponent`.
You can't use `useStore()` in the setup function of custom components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).